# SQL Server Left Join with Order BY

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-order-by

I have a Left Join SQL query (2012) that reports a 00:00:00 second execution time without the Order By clause at the bottom. Adding the "Order By" makes the query take 00:00:24 seconds!

Is this normal?

It's pretty clear that I'm missing some fairly fundamental concept here but I would have assumed that the query is performed and then the results sorted. Apparently this is not the case, please could anyone point me in the right direction?

A little other info: The two tables I'm joining have about 35,000 rows and 22,000 rows respectively. I'm selecting a date range and the left join is happening on two strings. The result set is between 300 - 400 results. I know that there's a massive penalty comparing strings and I'm guessing that's part of the problem here.

Here is the SQL:

```
DECLARE @mystartdate as datetime
SET @mystartdate = CAST(CAST((GETDATE() - 0) AS date) as nvarchar) + ' 06:00:00'

DECLARE @myenddate as datetime
SET @myenddate = CAST(CAST((GETDATE() + 1) AS date) as nvarchar) + ' 05:59:59'

SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST([Event_Time] AS nvarchar),0,9) AS mytime
,[CombinedDateTime]
,[MediaFileName]
,[Duration]
,[High_Definition]

FROM [dbo.schedules]

LEFT JOIN dbo.subtitles
ON REPLACE(SUBSTRING(dbo.subtitles.sub_filename, 1, LEN(dbo.subtitles.sub_filename) -4), '-', '') = REPLACE(dbo.schedules.MediaFileName,'/','')

WHERE [CombinedDateTime] >= @mystartdate AND [CombinedDateTime] <= @myenddate

Order by CombinedDateTime
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the SQL?

Comment: "Is this normal?" That really depends. What is your `ORDER BY` clause? What are the data types involved? Are there indexes to support your query? Clearly it has nothing to do with the volume of data but rather the sort operation(s) introduced by your desired ordering. We can't comment on that without more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal. With SQL and ORDER BY algorithms you get a performance hit with many many records, all depending on processors and other environmental factors. What you can do is set the two tables into a view. See if you compile the data into a predefined view if the performance improves.

Also you can use Data Transform and combine the data programmatically into it's own table on script, depending on how often you want to pull the data, if you need it real time, etc.

You have a few options though to research...

Comment: I've been trying nesting the parts of the SQL just now and that didn't help but will try a view now.

Comment: pugu, let me know if performance improves. I'm kind of curious too.

Comment: I think I might of fixed it thanks to you. Whilst going about creating a view I added a column and updated it with the results of the string expressions so instead of matching on: REPLACE(SUBSTRING(dbo.subtitles.sub_filename, 1, LEN(dbo.subtitles.sub_filename) -4), '-', '') I was matching on dbo.subtitles_at_rbm.truncated_filename which I'd already put the results from the previous query into. Lighting quick now so perhaps even though I was ordering on a date column those string operations were taking place over and over while it did it...?

Answer (score 2):

The `ORDER BY` order your results regarding your columns/rows.
Try set a index on all columns that you order and try again, this should help.